# No Royal Mail API, Safe to scrape?

Tags: jquery, api, post

I was looking around for a RM API where I could pass a tracking number to check the status of something I had posted. As I have read there is no such thing, so I was wondering would it be safe to post the tracking data to their processor i.e.:

```
$.post('http://www.royalmail.com/track-trace', {track_id: 'myTrackingNumber'}, success(data){
    // Get the HTML from the 'tnt-results' div and handle it.
})
```

Would Jquerys $.post work in this instance or are cross domain requests forbidden and I would have to do it in a PHP script using CURL?

My app will be hitting this regularly, I am thinking one call every 3 hours per tracking number, do you think that is reasonable or will they see lots of requests from the same IP and so will block me?

Answer (score 1):

> Would Jquerys $.post work in this instance or are cross domain requests

No, you will have to do it on the server.

Comment: +1 to counter -1... You are right, it would have to be done via CURL in a script, which would be called using $.ajax or $.post. I don't know why someone down voted you :/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `post` the tracking number. You just need to use the field `trackNumber` in the URL. A JavaScript example would be:

```
var trackingRef = "SC12345678901";
var trackingURL = "http://www.royalmail.com/track-trace?trackNumber="+trackingRef;
```

That page will tell you if the item is delivered or not, so you can then do what you need to do with that page.